# Pycharm Run/Debug not working with tensorflow

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pycharm

I am on Windows 7 with python 3.5.4 and Pycharm Community Edition 2017.2

When I execute my python script in the cmd.exe it works fine. But when using the Run or Debug tools in Pycharm I get this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xy\my_project\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\xy\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

Now I am familiar with this specific error. Usually this occures if Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (or Visual Studio) is not installed. But this is not the case since I have installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 (that's why the python script is working on the console).

My guess is, that I have to add some Path to Pycharm? But I do not know where or which one.

Comment: What is your Configurations for Run/Debug?

Comment: I changed the Python Interpreter to the one in my virtualenv. Other than that it is the default one. I am also using the virtualenv when executing with console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved the issue:

Open cmd.exe -> Create virtual env -> start Pycharm (pycharm.bat) from there

Comment: Can you give more explanation in more detail?