# Pycharm debug is not working with Tensorflow. How do I resolve it?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have successfully installed the following:

```
tensorflow (latest version 2.16.1)
keras (latest version 3.1.1
```

I am using pycharm 2023.3.5 (community Edition). I have some lines of codes with  imports including tensorflow:

```
...
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
...
```

Whenever, I debug my code, I get an error as seen below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.3.5\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_xml.py", line 177, in _get_type
if isinstance(o, t[0]):
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\flags.py", line 73, in __getattribute__
return self.__dict__['__wrapped'].__getattribute__(name)
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: '__wrapped'
```

I want to believe the problem is not caused by tensorflow but I can't seem to figure out the exact problem. I have surfed the internet but to no avail. The closest solution I got was this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486046/pycharm-run-debug-not-working-with-tensorflow), however, it appeared to me as a different problem. Please, learned people of this noble platform, come my aid.